# How to convert a HttpResponse StreamContent to zip file?

Tags: c#, api, http, stream, zip

I have an API which is returning `HTTPResponse` with  Content of type "Stream Content". Now i want to consume this API in another application and download the zip file sent as stream content. Can someone please suggest how can I achieve this in C#?

```
private HttpResponseMessage GetHttpResponseMessageForConfigFile(Component component)
{
    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    component.ConfigData = _configDataService.GetConfigDetail(component.Id).Data;
    var mermoryStream = new MemoryStream(component.ConfigData);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(mermoryStream);

    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = string.Format("{0}.zip", component.Code)
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}
```

In the above, `component.ConfigData` contains a byte array of zip file.

Comment: I was trying to use response.content.readasstreamasync but it was giving cannot convert string to to type stream error. I also tried to do typecasting but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You download a ZIP file like any other binary file as well:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"c:\path\to\file.zip");
}
```

Comment: Will it directly download the file at given file location?